# Why a rule to explicitly call a virtual base class constructor in initializer list of a most derived class, when an older ancestor already has it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

The following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Man
{
    int stories;

public:
    Man(int stories) : stories(stories) {cout << "A man is created with " << stories << " stories." << endl;};
};

class Grandpa : public virtual Man
{
    int pipes;

public:
    Grandpa(int stories, int pipes) : Man(1000), pipes(pipes)
    {
        stories += stories;
        cout << "Grandpa is created with " << stories << " stories and pipes." << endl;
    };
};

class Father : public Grandpa
{
    int cars;

public:
    Father(int stories, int cars) : Man(1000), Grandpa(1000, 1), cars(cars)
    {
        stories += stories;
        cout << "Father is created with " << stories << " stories and cars." << endl;
    };
};

class Son : public Father
{
    int girls;

public:
    Son(int stories, int girls) : Man(1000), Father(1000, 3), girls(girls)
    {
        stories += stories;
        cout << "Son is created with " << stories << " stories and girls." << endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Son Dick(1000, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output on the run:

**A man is created with 1000 stories.**

**Grandpa is created with 2000 stories and pipes.**

**Father is created with 2000 stories and cars.**

**Son is created with 2000 stories and girls.**

And it does not compile, when I do not call Man(int) in Father's and Son's initializers' lists. It is trying to call Man(void), and Man() is not defined. Why is it so? Yet, I think, when Father's or Son's constructors were called, the virtual base's constructor had already been called in Grandpa! Moreover thus, I would expect the output to be:

**A man is created with 1000 stories.**

**Grandpa is created with 2000 stories and pipes.**

**Father is created with 3000 stories and cars.**

**Son is created with 4000 stories and girls.**

To recapitulate then: why a virtual base class constructor has to be called explicitly in an initializer list of a derived class, although it is already placed in an younger's ancestor initializer list? Why it is seemingly not called in the younger ancestor, and a default base class is tried to be called instead?

**EDIT due to finding an answer to problem with numbers**
What a shame :) I should have made `int stories` in Grandpa `protected int _stories;` and then the output would be as expected: 1000 stories for Man, 2000 for Grandpa, 3000 for Father and 4000 for Dick :) Otherwise `stories += stories` acts on local variable instead of the Man's member... Sorry for bothering!

Answer (score 2):

The call to the virtual base's constructor comes from the most-derived type of the object being created. In this case, that's `Son`, so `Son` needs to call `Man`'s constructor.

However, it's also possible to create a `Father` that isn't actually a `Son` (e.g., `main` having `Father Dick(1000, 5)`). Because of that, `Father` might end up being the one to initialize `Man`, meaning it needs to call `Man`'s constructor. The same is true for `Grandpa`.

If you make `Man`, `Grandpa`, and `Father` abstract classes, they can no longer possibly be the ones to initialize `Man`, and thus do not need a call to its constructor. However, GCC 6.1 gives me an error when I do this (Clang compiles it). I believe GCC to be wrong here.

Comment: Thank You. I think however this is not the answer I was looking for. My question is of an academic kind. I will try to ask the same again in a comment to a duplicate claim.

Comment: Aha, I also have to admit, I do not understand, why the numbers in the program do not increase :( When I call Man(1000) in Son(1000), I would suppose, that call of Father(1000) would add 1000 to stories, and in Father's constructor, the call to Grandpa(1000) would add 1000 stories as well. So I expected 3000 stories in Father's case and 4000 stories in Son's. But all in all each derived classes constructor prints out only 2000 stories.

Comment: Ok, I have responded myself to that in the next edit...