# In a diamond problem in c++ , Why do we need to call grand_parent constructor from child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, diamond-problem

Please read the code to understand the situation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class one
{
protected:
    int x;
public:
    one(int a)
    {
        x=a;
        cout << "one cons called\n";
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    }
    ~one()
    {
        cout << "one destroy\n";
    }
};
class two : virtual protected one
{
protected:
    int y;
public:
    two(int a,int b) : one(a),y(b)
    {
        cout << "two cons called\n";
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        one::display();
        cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    }
    ~two()
    {
        cout << "two destroy\n";
    }
};

class three : protected virtual one
{
protected:
    int z;
public:
    three(int a,int b) : one(a),z(b)
    {
        cout << "Three cons called\n";
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        one::display();
        cout << "z = " << z << endl;
    }
    ~three()
    {
        cout << "three destroy\n";
    }
};

class four : private two, private three
{
public:
    four(int a,int b,int c) :one(a), two(a,b),three(a,c)
    {
        cout << " four cons called\n";
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        one::display();
        cout << "y = " << y << endl;
        cout << "z = " << z << endl;
    }
    ~four()
    {
        cout << "four destroy\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    four ob(1,2,3);
    ob.display();
    return 0;
}
```

If i replace the code

```
four(int a,int b,int c) :one(a), two(a,b),three(a,c)
```

with

```
four(int a,int b,int c) :two(a,b),three(a,c)
```

an error messege like : no matching function for call to 'one::one()' occurs in my codeblock ide.

As you can see this is a code based on diamond problem.Where class one is the grand_parent class . Class two and three serving as parent class and class four as child class. So i used the virtual keyword to avoid ambiguity. Everything I understand here unless 1 thing.I know that when a parent class has parameterized constructor we need to supply arguments to that constructor from the derived class. So then Why do need to supply argument to the constructor one where class four has only 2 parent class that is two and three .
The code will give me compile time error if i don't call constructor one from the class four. Please explain me why we need to do so.

Comment: There's a few suspect things about the code and classes you show. Like for example why do you override the ***non***-virtual function `display` in all classes? And why do you have `private` inheritance? Private inheritance is usually recommended against in favor of composition.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude .I wrote this code for learning purposes , didn't write this  for real project

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324583/why-must-virtual-base-classes-be-constructed-by-the-most-derived-class

Answer (score 19):

The `virtual` inheritance in your hierarchy disambiguates the existence of the base class `one` by making sure that only one single instance of `one` is stored in subclasses of `two` or `three`. Recall that when inheriting some class, a derived instance will always store a base instance somehere internally - so `virtual` inheritance ensures that the instances of `one` inside of `two` and `three` are somewhat "overridden" by any class further down the inheritance hierarchy.

Now the question is: who is responsible for initializing this one single `one` instance? Should it be `two` or `three`? Clearly not both of them, as there is only one instance. And here you are: it's always the *most derived* class that's responsible for the initialization of `one` - and that makes sense: the instance that embeds a base class copy must initialize it.

This is how the class hierarchy with embedded base class instances looks like without `four` and with `four` plus `virtual` inheritance:

```
              +----------+                           +----------+
              |   one    |                           |   one    |
              +----+-----+                           +----+-----+
                   |                                      |
                   |                                      |
         +-------+-----------+           virtual +--------+--------+ virtual
         |                   |                   |                 |
         |                   |                   |                 |
+--------+-------+   +-------+-------+      +----+----+       +----+----+
|      two       |   |      three    |      |  two    |       |  three  |
| +------------+ |   | +----------+  |      +----+----+       +----+----+
| |   one      | |   | |   one    |  |           |                 |
| +------------+ |   | +----------+  |           +--------+--------+
|  => must init! |   | => must init! |                    |
+----------------+   +---------------+            +-------+--------+
                                                  |     four       |
                                                  | +------------+ |
                                                  | |    one     | |
                                                  | +------------+ |
                                                  | => must init!  |
                                                  +----------------+
```

You can think of this mechanism this way: `virtual` inheritance gives the base class instance `virtual`-ness, and that includes constructing the instance - this responsability is passed down the hierarchy.

Comment: Did you create that diagram by hand or with a tool?

Comment: @0x499602D2 First draft [here](http://asciiflow.com/), then some visual block editing in vim.

Answer (score 7):

Say you have the following diamond:

```
     Base
    /    \
 Left    Right
    \    /
     Down
```

The `Base` class can be very simple, it has a single `int` member that is initialized by the constructor:

```
struct Base
{
    Base(int x) 
        : x(x)
    {}
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    int x;
};
```

Since `Left` inherits from `Base`, its constructor can pass arguments to the `Base` constructor. Here, if you construct a `Left` object, its `x` member will be `1`:

```
struct Left : virtual Base
{
    Left() : Base(1)
    {}
};
```

The other class, `Right`, also inherits from `Base`. This means that its constructor can also pass arguments to the `Base` constructor. Here, its `x` member will be `2`:

```
struct Right : virtual Base
{
    Right() : Base(2)
    {}
};
```

Now comes the fun part: What happens if you inherit from both `Left` and `Right`?

```
// This does not compile.
struct Down : Left, Right
{
    Down() : Left(), Right()
    {}
};
```

Both `Left` and `Right` call the `Base` constructor, but they use different arguments. Should the compiler now use the `Base(1)` part from `Left` or should it use the `Base(2)` part from `Right`? The answer is simple: It uses neither! The compiler leaves the choice to you and allows you to specify which constructor should be used:

```
// Hooray, this version compiles.
struct Down : Left, Right
{
    Down() : Base(42), Left(), Right()
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The Diamond problem happens when two super classes of a class have a common base class. 
The solution for this problem is “Virtual” keyword.  In general case it is not allowed to call the grandparent’s constructor directly, it has to be called through parent class. It is allowed only when we use “Virtual” keyword. 
SO, when we use ‘virtual’ keyword, the default constructor of grandparent class is called by default even if the parent classes explicitly call parameterized constructor.